# Mysqli real escape string, how to parse

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, escaping

I have class where is mysqli connect and i need to escape variables from another class ( not in this construct ) but in class above down.

```
public function __construct(){

            require_once(__DIR__."/../config/config.php");
            $mysqli = new mysqli($config['db_hostname'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'], $config['db_name']);

            if($mysqli->connect_errno)
            {
                printf("Připojení selhalo %s\n",$mysqli->connect_error());
                exit();

            }

            $this->connection = $mysqli;
            mysqli_set_charset($this->connection, $config['charset']);

            if($this->isLoginPage()){

            }else{
                //DIE pokud není přihlášený ----------------------------
            if(!$this->isLogged()[0]->id and $_GET['qr'] != 1){
                die("Nepovolený přístup.");
            }
            //------------------------------------------------
        }
        }




        public function insert($query){
            $result = $this->connection->query($query);

            return $this->connection->insert_id;
        }

        public function update($query)
        {
            $result = $this->connection->query($query);
        }
```

I need to parse mysqli_real_escape_string from another class in sql. Code looks like.

```
function updatePageSettings($array){
            global $db;

            $query = "UPDATE settings set setting_page='".$array."'";

            return $db->update($query);
        }
```

I need to escape $array ( somethink like mysqli_real_escape_string($array) in $query). Thank for any response!

Comment: what is stored on $array variable? is it an array ? if so your query is also wrong here.

Comment: Works fine, but i cant update record with slashes.

Comment: use prepared statements and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another method in your class establishing the database connection and all.

```
public function escape($string){
  return $this->connection->real_escape_string($string);
}
```

and then the update settings function as follow

```
function updatePageSettings($array){
   global $db;

   $query = "UPDATE settings set setting_page='".$db->escape($array)."'";

   return $db->update($query);
}
```

Comment: Thank! I see... but I didn't have mind on this :-D so simple :D